# OCUnit on Snow Leopard VS Leopard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I am working on a iPhone project that just added a second developer.  The new developer got a new shiny macbookpro with snow leopard and Xcode 3.2.  I am still on leopard and using Xcode 3.1.

He is getting errors trying to run the unit tests (OCUnit and OCMock are being used).

The shell script as the last step of the Test Target fails with a -1.

Any ideas as to what is happening, or suggestions to fix?

It blows up calling RunTestsForBundle but that is where we get stumped.  Is RunTestsForBundle a script, but I can't find it anywhere on my hard drive?

Comment: This isn't a real answer, but gh-unit is a nice alternative to OCUnit and includes a GUI so you can choose which tests to run: http://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like OCMock was not setup correctly in the Tests target.  I needed a copy files step in between the Compile Sources and Copy Bundle Resources for OCMock.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had problems myself, so I can't verify this, but I've heard that Xcode 3.2.1 (for iPhone OS 3.1.2) fixes some unit test related issues as well.

Comment: Yes, that did fix one issue, but it only allowed us to get a little further.  Before 3.1.2 Xcode would freeze and he would have to kill it whenever attempting to run the tests.  So it is an improvement.  Thanks.